# C# implement generic interface like IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way to build an interface like IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>

```
public interface IFoo {
    object Bar { get; }
}

public interface IFoo<T> : IFoo {
    T Bar { get; }
}

public class Test : IFoo<int> {
    public new int Bar => 1;
}
```

this throw an error:

> Error: (9.21): Error CS0738: 'Test' does not implement interface
> member 'IFoo.Bar'. 'Test.Bar' cannot implement 'IFoo.Bar' because it
> does not have the matching return type of 'object'.

Comment: Remove `new`. That introduces a *new* method that's different from any base method with the same name

Answer (score 1):

When implementing an interface your method-signature has to match **exactly**. `T`simply does not match `object`. In particular a `struct` is not an `object`.  So your class has to implement both the generic and the un-generic interface:

So just do this:

```
public interface IFoo {
    object Bar { get; }
}

public interface IFoo<T> : IFoo {
    T Bar { get; }
}

public class Test : IFoo<int> {
    public int Bar => 1;  // implementation for the generic interface
    object IFoo.Bar => (object) Bar; // explicit implementation for the un-generic interface
}
```

Comment: that is not entirely true anymore see: [C# 9.0 Covariant returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns)